# Unable to use DBpedia Spotlight statistical endpoint?

Tags: java, spotlight-dbpedia

I wrote some code that uses the Lucene endpoint at http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/.  It works, but I wanted to see how the results differed from the Statistical endpoint.  When I tried changing the URL in my code to http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest, however, I get a "Stream Closed" Java IO exception.  The code is otherwise identical.

The URL changes from

```
http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate/?confidence=0.2&support=20&text=<my URL-encoded text>

to 
http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest/annotate/?confidence=0.2&support=20&text=<my URL-encoded text>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the endpoint is currently down.
Worth trying in a few hours, or you can set up your own spotlight server very easily

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried for a few days, but when I asked the same question on the mailing list, someone restarted the server and I was able to try my query.